# Delete data from memory

Tags: ruby, memory, memory-management

I have a script which is supposed to get big JSON files (100mb) (streamed over multiple parts) and parse them, I want to use the script repeatedly without closing it, however upon finishing with the data it stays in my memory and I can't find a way to remove it, tried: creating a thread then killing it (assuming that it's local variables data will be wiped), as you can see below use global variable and edit them did not work too, tried clearing the array named "get" here using get.clear too,

there is a method called handle used in this script, that one takes the part of the data received and parse it in a new thread to reduce processing time ( each thread takes a portion of the data so we can say they are part of the problem, I don't mind sharing it's code should it be necessary

the question would be how can I remove the data from my memory ?

side questions:

1) why killing a thread does not remove it's data from the memory ?

2)why after resetting a variable's value it's data is still left in my memory ?

3)why does the new data gets addition(+) to the old data even thought I set a new value to the same variable ?

sorry I tried looking in stackoverflow and google but i can't seem to find a solution/answer

```
    def getinventory(needed)
    $to_kill = Thread.new do
    $items = needed
    $threadnumber = -1
    $itemstoget = []
    $arryofthreads = []
    $parsed = 0
    $found = false
    last_id = 0
    first = true
    loginv("inventory fetch initiated")
    right = false
    until last_id == "end" || $found == true
      if first == "no"
        sleep(0.2)
      end
      right = false
      until right == true
        begin
           get = JSON.parse(RestClient.get("http://steamcommunity.com/inventory/76561198044170935/753/6?start_assetid=#{last_id}&count=5000"))
           right = true
         rescue
           logmain("rescued")
         end
       end
      if first == true
        handle(get.values[0],get.values[1])
        first = false
        if get.keys[3].to_s == "last_assetid"
          last_id = get.values[3].to_s
        else
          last_id = "end"
        end
      elsif first == false
        handle(get.values[0],get.values[1])

        if get.keys[3].to_s == "last_assetid"
          last_id = get.values[3].to_s
        else
          last_id = "end"
        end
      end
    end
    get.clear
    $items = ""
    $threadnumber = -1
    $itemstoget = []
    $arryofthreads = []
    $parsed = 0
    $found = false
  end
end
```

Comment: What do you mean by _remove from memory_? Do you want the data to be overwritten to ensure that dumping the memory to disk doesn't contain the data anymore? Or do you just want to free the memory that it can be used by other data? Btw. why do you use global variables for your values?

Comment: Ruby is garbage collected so don't expect "freeing" memory in your script to automatically release said memory back to the OS.

Comment: @spickermann this script upon execution will load approximatively 500mb into my computers RAM EACH TIME i execute it ( i use it through a socket, a loop inside) so 2 executions i'd have 1gb used, 3 executions i have 1.5gb and so on, i want it to use only 500mb of memory even after 3 executions  ... i used global variables cause : this script will look for a  certain card in a big steam inventory, i divide each 5k inventory item to one thread, and each thread looks for the card, should  one of the threads find the card i need to stop requesting data from steam to save processing time